# dagger2 compilation errors are missing

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am having problems with reading dagger2 compilation errors. For example I have an annotation NotNull for which I have not provided properly a dependency in build.gradle, but dagger does not give the actual cause of the compilation error but shows only this for a file with the problem:

> error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.inter
> nal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class
> because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for
> compila tion errors or a circular dependency with generated code.

final error comes from kapt:

> A failure occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

I am always able to somehow track the cause of the problem, but its very frustrating. Above problem with NotNull would normally end up as a compilation error, but because dagger runs before compilation I have no chance to see this error.

Is there some option to make dagger more verbose with errors? I have lifter error limit to 2500 but still no better errors appear.

I currently use AGP 7.0.1 and dagger2 in version 2.38.1

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue last time but managed to solve the issue by deleting the "build" folder of the project.

[image]

But in the end, I couldn't figure out the root cause of the issue.

Try to delete these build folders and rebuild the project, if you haven't tried.

Comment: Works for me. Same can also be achieved with Build -> Clean Project